# How to install package `tabu`?

Tags: texlive, longtable, tabu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

I want to include style sheet `tabu.sty` when compile. Currently, the following error will be reported

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tabu.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

How to install the missing package? Simply copy the `.sty` file into some directory?

My environment is `TexLive 2009`, `Ubuntu`.

Comment: See [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: The short answer though is: just put it next to your .tex file. It will only work for this one document but depending on what you want this might be the easiest solution.